# Global variable does not take new value

Tags: c

I was making a simple C program

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int a;
a = 5;
int main()
{
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

Compiler error: "non static declaration of 'a' follows static declaration"

What does this error mean?

Comment: +1 , If this question was asked in my placement I will definitely answer it wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what this error log means?

It is a little tricky: what looks like an assignment

```
a = 5;
```

is treated as

```
int a = 5;
```

due to an old C rule that allowed you to declare `int` variables and int-returning functions without specifying their type explicitly (this is definitely not a good idea in the modern version of C).

Note that this is treated as a declaration with an implicit `int` only in the scope outside a function body.

You can fix it by combining the declaration with initialization, like this:

```
static int a = 5;
```

Comment: Note that since C99 standard such implicit `int` is not valid anymore (though for GCC `-pedantic-errors` is needed to issue an error).

Comment: so first is a declaration making 'a' as static and another is an initialization of same variable as non static.

Comment: @mrigendra Yes, the second one is a declaration/initialization of the same variable as non-static.

Answer (score 3):

Outside a function you can only declare variables, you cannot have actual code statements.

```
a = 5;
```

is being interpreted as another declaration, when your intent I think is to write some code.

instead declare and initialise a at the same time

```
 static int a = 5;
```

Comment: This is not a statement, it is a declaration with default type `int`.

Comment: that's what the compiler knows, but coder intended to write a statment

Comment: if i remove static the error goes but one warning as 'data definintion has no type or storage class' remains.

Answer (score 1):

Your first declaration of `a` is `static` (`a`has internal linkage).

The second declaration is not `static` (`a` has external linkage). Yes, `a = 5;` is a declaration with implicit type `int` in this case.

Both do not agree.

Btw. for functions this would be o.k. because the second declaration would "inherit" the internal linkage.

Answer (score 1):

***We cannot write any assignment statement globally. For example:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int i=10;   //Initialization statement
i=25;              //Assignment statement
int main(){
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}

Output: Compilation error
```

Note: Assigning any value to the `variable` at the time of `declaration` is known as `initialization` while assigning any value to variable not at the time of declaration is known `assignment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set value as you did it: `a = 5;` before `main(...)`. See code below:

```
static int a = 1; //default = 0;

int main()
{
    printf("a = %d\n", a);

    a = 2;

    printf("a = %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A = 5 is considered as an attempt to create another variable called a. You should put the = 5 after static int a.

```
Static int a = 5;
```

Comment: You should switch off auto-correction when writing code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little modification to your code will help you to understand it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//static int a;   //comment this statement
a = 5;
int main()
{
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

now compile this code [please enable your compiler's warnings]

Then you will get a warning something like this
***data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]***

So now try to understand this warning it means that compiler treat statement `a=5` as a definition but without data type. But compiler unable default data type that is int.

so this statement is equivalent to

```
int a=5;
```